# Post MVC view data with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

HI,
I am sending Product Model to my controller method. i am getting string for posted form. it need to send it in key/value pair or whole product model. Any help would be apprecaited.

```
 var link = '/Product/AddRec?callback=?';

 var formdata = $("form").serialize(); 
               $.ajax({
                   url: link,
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: { 
                        'obj' : formdata,
                       'jin': 1,
                       'deb': 2)
                   },
                   dataType: "jsonp"

               });
```

Comment: Why are you including `<br />` tags in your javascript?

Comment: sorry ignore <br /> i did to format post here

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Product/AddRec?callback=?',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("form").serialize() + "&jin=1&deb=2"
});
```

edit:

as Darin Dimitrov requested, here go my humble explanation

Consider my Product class

```
public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I suppose your action is something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRec(Product product, int jin, int deb) {
    // code
}
```

The form

```
<form id="productForm">
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Id) %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name) %>
    <input type="button" value="Send form" onclick="SendForm();" />
</form>
```

Suppose that Id = "1" and Name = "Darin Dimitrov".

jQuery will serialize my form like this

Id=1&Name=Darin+Dimitrov

and will concat with the extra data to become

Id=1&Name=Darin+Dimitrov&jin=1&deb=2

```
<script type="javascript/text">
    function SendForm() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/AddRec?callback=?',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#productForm").serialize() + "&jin=1&deb=2"
        });
    }
</script>
```

the action should receive

```
product.Id = 1
product.Name = "Darin Dimitrov"
jin = 1
deb = 2
```

that's all, sorry If I can't help you OP.

Comment: That's odd, here works. Do you have another solution to share with us @Darin Dimitrov?

Comment: @Kim Tranjan, no, I don't, because I don't know what is being asked here :-) The OPs question is not clear to me. I don't know what is his scenario and what is he trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kim Tranjan, so probably you could explain better what is this code supposed to do? What is the actual request being sent? How does the controller action would look like, etc ...?

Comment: @Kim Tranjan, excellent answer, +1. It's a pity I can't upvote your answer multiple times. I don't know if this is the OPs scenario but your answer is definitely very good now and should serve as example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jQuery [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) to do this. It handles serializing the form contents and, if you look at the options, you can specify additional data. Your example above would become:

```
$.ajaxSubmit({
                   url: link,
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: { 
                       'jin': 1,
                       'deb': 2)
                   },
                   dataType: "jsonp"

               });
```

It takes care of serializing the form and sending the data to the server in the appropriate form.